# Determine all real polynomial solutions y of a differential equation

Tags: integration, derivatives, polynomials

Determine all real polynomial solutions y of a differential equation

$$y'(x) = 5x^7 + 4x^5 + 3x^3 +  x + 8$$

for all real numbers $x$.

Any hints for starting this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just need to integrate your equation

Comment: You just need to find the anti-derivative of this polynomial.

Comment: It must be an 8th degree polynomial. Pick an arbitrary one, differentiate and see what this implies about the coefficients.

Comment: I think an initial condition is missing.

Answer (score 2):

$$y'(x) = 5x^7 + 4x^5 + 3x^3 +  x + 8 \implies y(x) = \int(5x^7+4x^5 + 3x^3 + x + 8)\,dx$$

Upon integrating, you will have a family of degree-eight polynomials which differ only by a constant.

$$y(x) = \frac 58 x^8 + \frac 23 x^6+ \frac 34 x^4 +\frac 12x^2 + 8x + C, \;\;C\in \mathbb R$$

The solution then, isa family of degree-8 polynomials which differ only by a constant. That is, only $C$ varies among these polynomials.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback! I think I am confused as to what the question is asking. Would the integral of y′(x) suffice as the answer? Sorry if this doesn't make sense. English is not my or my instructor's first language.

Comment: The polynomial solutions consists of all polynomials which result after integrating $y'$, plus a constant. $y(x) = p(x) + C$ where $p(x)$ is the polynomial after integrating, and C is the constant of integration. $C \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the polynomial $y'(x)$ has a single real solution ($x \approx -0.9039$), which is the point that minimizes $y(x)$ (because the coefficient of $x^8$ is positive and it is an even degree polynomial).

Solving the integral, we have
$$ y(x) = \frac{5}{8}x^8 + \frac{2}{3}x^6+ \frac{3}{4}x^4 +\frac{1}{2}x^2 + 8x +C.$$

When $C = 0$, the polynomial has only two real solutions: $x =0$ or $x \approx -1.2793.$ The minimal value is $y(-0.9039) \approx -5.6799.$

Notice that $C$ is just a translation of the polynomial curve. Thus, if $C > 5.6799$, the polynomial has no real solutions, if $C = 5.6799$ the polynomial has one real solution, and when $C < 5.6799$, the polynomial has two real solutions.